# If JVM is software, how does it actually compile and translate code that the machine can understand?

Tags: compilation, translation, bytecode, low-level

So "JVM compiles the source code into bytecode, and then translate it into a native machine code that the local computer understands, and with which JVM can interact with the local OS".

But if on a low-level (and very simplified) operations are ultimately performed by hardware interactions, i.e. reading/writing from/to charges of memory cells (transistors and capacitors), how does JVM translate code?

What happens behind the scenes (on a lower-level)?

Statement: I imagine, since Java is a downloaded program on my computer, it has already the bytecode information needed to instruct or interact with my OS, and send the instructions to the hardware to ultimately actually perform the compilation and translation or something like that?

EDIT: I am very new to CS, so I suppose my phrasing is probably misleading. My question is really if my Statement is correct? And if not, then how does it happen?

Because ultimately JVM can (and must) indirectly manage the hardware parts in order to perform operations and calculations. These operations and calculations can be performed by the hardware (reading/writing from/to the charges of the memory cells) only through binary code, which is generated after compilation and translation.

I am assuming the process of getting from a source code to a binary code must ultimately also be performed by the hardware, hence my question and my Statement.

TIA

Comment: Machine code is just bytes in memory.  Software can create that (JIT compile) and then jump to those bytes to execute them.  Mainstream computers are Von Neumann architectures where there's no strict separation between code and data.  I'd have thought that most JVMs would be JITing machine code that makes system calls, so the last part of that description seems misleading to me: interaction with the OS would normally happen by JITed code calling back into ahead-of-time compiled functions in the JVM executable.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM does not compile the code. This is done by using javac which compiles the source code to bytecode. The bytecode is then interpreted by the JVM upon application launch using java.exe (or java or Linux). Yet, the parts of the bytecode that are heavily executed (the hotspots) are jitted (just in time compiled to native code) during execution.